# Sum of multinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, multinomial-coefficients

It is well-known (using for example the Vandermonde's convolution identity) that
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^n{n \choose j}^2={2n \choose n}.$$
During my calculation I got the following sum
$$\sum\limits_{k_1+...+k_n=k}{k \choose k_1,...,k_n}^2,$$
with ${k \choose k_1,...,k_n}$ being the multinomial coefficients.

Is the value of this sum known in literature? (I didn't find neither any formula which can allow for computation of it nor the combinatorial proof.) Any hints?

Comment: maybe this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128249/estimate-on-sum-of-squares-of-multinomial-coefficients can help

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like there are only Stirling-like approximations. I am still looking for some other references with exact values or relations to other combinatorial numbers etc.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A002893, http://oeis.org/A002895, http://oeis.org/A169714, ...

Comment: https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/walks.pdf seems to summarise what's known.

Comment: Are you summing over partitions of all lengths ($n$ is a summation variable), or partitions of a single length ($n$ is a given input)? Are you summing over ordered or unordered partitions of $k$? Are the $k_i$ allowed to be zero?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is $\sum\limits_{k_1+...+k_n=k}$ equivalent to $\sum\limits_{k_1=0}^k\dots \sum\limits_{k_n=0}^k$?